# Why is the product of two matrices the product of their partitions?

Tags: matrices

I'm working through Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS), and it presents a recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm for multiplying any two $n \times n$ matrices (where $n$ is an integer power of $2$) as follows:

To compute the product $C = A \cdot B$, we partition each of $A, B, C$ into four $n/2 \ \times \ n/2$ matrices $$A = \begin{bmatrix}{} A_{11} \ A_{12} \\ A_{21}\  A_{22}\end{bmatrix}, \ B = \begin{bmatrix}{} B_{11} \ B_{12} \\ B_{21}\  B_{22}\end{bmatrix}, \ C = \begin{bmatrix}{} C_{11} \ C_{12} \\ C_{21}\  C_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$ so that $$\begin{bmatrix}{} C_{11} \ C_{12} \\ C_{21}\  C_{22}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{} A_{11} \ A_{12} \\ A_{21}\  A_{22}\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}{} B_{11} \ B_{12} \\ B_{21}\  B_{22}\end{bmatrix} \ $$

Obviously, this works when $A_{ij}, B_{ij}, C_{ij}$ are just scalars (it's the definition of matrix multiplication), but why is this necessarily valid for **any** square matrix (if $A_{ij}, B_{ij}, C_{ij}$ are themselves matrices)? How do we know that we can just partition each of matrices $A$ and $B$ into four $n/2 \ \times \ n/2$ matrices, and that multiplying these matrices will give us the entries for the answer?

Is there a name for this theorem? The book doesn't mention it and assumes that it's a given, but I don't find it quite as obvious. Is there any intuition/ proof of why this works as intended?

Comment: For each individual entry of $C$, write down how it is computed in terms of the entries of $A$ and $B$. For the particular sub-matrix $C_{ij}$ that contains this entry, you can also write down an expression for this entry in terms of the entries of submatrices of $A$ and $B$. Showing these two are equal amounts to some rearranging/grouping of terms.

Comment: The formula for the product is valid for matrices with coefficients in *any* ring, in particular if the coefficient ring is the ring of $n/2\times n/2$ matrices.

Comment: @angryavian I've got $$C_{11} = A_{11} B_{21}+A_{12}B_{21}+\cdots + A_{1n}B_{n1}$$, but in order to compare this to the $C_{11}$ as claimed in the formula, I'd have to divide each of $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$ into four $n/2 \ \times \ n/2$ matrices, and multiply each of those submatrices, but in order to do that, I'd have to split each of **those** into submatrices. I would then have to do this for every index. I don't know how I'd do this. Is there a name for the theorem that makes the claim in question?

Comment: @Bernard What do you mean by "ring" in this context? Could you give me an example of a non-square matrix (or a square matrix that is not a power of two) for which this applies? How would you even split such a matrix up into equal-sized submatrices?

Comment: Your submatrices are not square matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment:

If $c_{ij}$ is the $i,j$ entry of $C$, then
$$c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}$$
You can rewrite the right-hand side as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} a_{ik} b_{kj} + \sum_{k=n/2+1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}.$$

This will correspond to the multiplication via sub-matrices. If for example $c_{ij}$ lies in $C_{11}$, then the above corresponds to how $C_{11} = A_{11}B_{11} + A_{12} B_{21}$ contributes to the entry $c_{ij}$.

---

More generally, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication); basically any partitioning of $A$, $B$, and $C$ into block matrices is valid, as long as the dimensions match up so that multiplication of the sub-matrices is valid.

Comment: Shouldn't the LHS of your sum be from $k=1$ to $n/4$, not $n/2$, as you're computing four separate matrices?

I'm finding it really hard to understand why this is the case. Is there an intuitive explanation as to why this is? I've tried proving the "theorem" by induction, but there's lots of messy algebra and as I said, I'm stuck computing loads and loads of submatrices.

Comment: @Spongebob My answer is a proof. All I have done is split the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n$ into two pieces: $\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}$ and $\sum_{k=n/2+1}^n$. The sub-matrix multiplication is $C_{11} = A_{11} B_{11} + A_{12} B_{21}$, which involves multiplication of $n/2 \times n/2$ matrices. There is no $n/4$.

Comment: What does each of the sums correspond to (which submatrices in $C$)?

Comment: @Spongebob The sums are an expression for *one* entry in $C$, namely $c_{ij}$. It lies in *one* submatrix of $C$. If it lies in $C_{11}$, then note that $C_{11} = A_{11} B_{11} + A_{12} B_{21}$, and the first sum represents the contribution of the matrix $A_{11} B_{11}$ to the *entry* $c_{ij}$ while the second sum represents the contribution of the matrix $A_{12} B_{21}$ to the *entry* $c_{ij}$; if it lies in $C_{12}$, then note that $C_{12} = A_{11} B_{12} + A_{12} B_{22}$; etc.

Comment: I get that, but what does $$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}a_{ik}b_{kj}$$ respresent, and what does $$\sum_{k=n/2+1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{kj}$$ respresent? Surely, you're splitting the matrix into **four** submatrices, each of length $n/2$, **not** two, so there must be four summations?

Comment: @Spongebob Think about matrix multiplication, and how you compute a particular *entry* $c_{ij}$ of $C$. You take the "dot product" of the $i$th row of $A$ with the $j$ column of $B$. The first summation is just computing the dot product of the first half of the row of $A$ with the first half of the column of $B$, while the second summation is just computing the dot product of the second half of the row of $A$ with the second half of the column of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the multiplication of two matrices depends on the multiplication of a row by a column, or, in other words, a row vector by a column vector. This is just the dot product of two vectors which is a sum of the products of corresponding elements of the two vectors. This summation can be split in many ways by partitioning the index set into a collection of subsets. For exmaple, $$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)\cdot(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5) = a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3+a_4b_4+a_5b_5$$
can also be computed as 
$$(a_1,a_3,a_5)\cdot(b_1,b_3,b_5)+(a_2,a_4)\cdot(b_2,b_4)=(a_1b_1+a_3b_3+a_5b_5)+(a_2b_2+a_4b_4).$$
This demonstrates the idea that you can partition matrices into rectangular   blocks and multiply partitioned matrices regarding the blocks as if they were themselves matrix elements.